# É preciso ter calma, refletir em caso de dúvida e se não souber não ir com o rebanho

Tags: debate

Hoje deparei-me com uma pergunta a perguntar como [estender um objeto em javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90290/129).

Reparei [numa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/90301/129) com `-9`, fortemente penalizada e que estava... correta!

O que aconteceu? Bom, não posso falar por aqueles que votaram negativo. Mas a resposta responde com javaScript ES6, ou seja a versão mais recente de JavaScript ainda não adoptada por muitos browsers.

A resposta tem JavaScript válido mas porém desconhecido aos olhos destreinados e que não estejam a par dos novos brinquedos que JavaScript ES6 traz: *Classes* e como extendê-las.

A meu ver a resposta não merece `-9`. Se alguém quiser ir lá e dar uma segunda chance a um utilizador novo do site, que respondeu com código do futuro [aqui fica o link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/90301/129), acho que ele merecia uma segunda oportunidade.

Comment: Pelo pouco tempo de SO que tenho já percebi que é ver um sinal de "-" á frente de algum número que lá vem muitos outros negativos em sequência. Ocorreu comigo quando dei uma resposta, e em menos de 40 segundos percebi que não tinha colocado conteúdo suficiente nela e fui editar. Mas antes disso já recebi um -1, e assim foi, -2, até o "count++" esgotar, rs... Após editar, e o autor RECONHECER que minha resposta era válida e que tentei ajudar, sumiram quase instantâneamente os pontos negativos... A minha conclusão é que muitos usuários lutam por pontos aqui e não conhecimento ou ajuda ao próximo

Comment: Que tal criarmos a tag `rebanho`? E marcar `manada` como sinônimo? :D

Comment: Já aconteceu isso com uma pergunta minha. rsrsrs

Comment: @Math, boa ideia. Pode mesmo ser um padrão de comportamento que tenha a sua discussão de vez em quando.

Comment: @Sergio, será que o critério não foram pessoas que testaram e viu que deu erro? Acho que o navegador acusa até que `class` é uma palavra reservada

Comment: @Sergio, o pior problema é quando não há o reconhecimento que você teve. As vezes acontece de algo permanecer negativado, como se estivesse errado.

Comment: Isto está acontecendo cada vez mais e em várias formas. Não sei exatamente sobre a resposta mas confio no Sergio e me parece que na pior das hipóteses, lendo a pergunta, ela merece placar zero. Talvez positivo. O negativo seria justificável, mas nem tanto se a pergunta especificasse que não pode ser ES6. Claro que seria melhor se ela tivesse feito a ressalva. Esta é uma das edições de terceiros que de certa forma altera o sentido, mas é positiva. Também não sei o quanto é certo dar positivo agora. O ideal seria só tirar os -1. Se agora acha que merece +1,ok,mas só para compensar,não acho legal

Comment: @WallaceMaxters até pode ser. Mas o AR merece o beneficio da dúvida. Concordo que o AR podia ter explicado que se refere a ES6, mas quem votou parece não estar sufecientemente informado sobre JavaScript para o fazer. Pelo menos não merece um `-9`. Daí ter lançado o debate aqui.

Comment: @Sergio, acho que tem muita gente que vai votando _efeito cascata_. tipo: "tem um -1 ali, então vou votar negativo também".

Comment: "Mário vai com os outros" existem muito por essas redondezas, mesmo que ao meu ver receber negativo não é ofensa, vejo alguns usuários "OMG, RECEBI -1, NAAAAAAAAO". Meu conceito pessoal é negativar apenas o que vejo que não tem sentido algum, e não como forma de agressão ou ofensa, mas sim uma simples sinalização para melhoria e reformulação da pergunta ou resposta.

Comment: @mauriciocaserta, você acha que o fato de ele não ter especificado o `Es6` merecia -1?

Comment: @WallaceMaxters não, não acho, por ele tentar ajudar com uma resposta, pode ter se esquecido de especificar algo, acontece... Ainda mais por ser uma tentativa de ajuda, ressalto : voluntária.

Comment: @Math, esse `manada` vale tanto para os dois lados, tanto para os downvotes como para os upvotes.

Comment: Depois de analisar, eu me sinto seguro em votar agora e acho que a resposta merece até um +1 (que ainda não posso dar por ter estourado meus votos do dia). Ela é boa, na versão atual. Só que agora ficou um situação esquisita porque esta resposta já está com mais positivos que a melhor resposta para a situação atual. O Sergio fez muito bem de postar aqui, mas gerou outro "maria vai com as outras" :D

Comment: @WallaceMaxters e não para por aí, ainda tem as filas de análise

Comment: @Math, eu reparei. No início, eu me lembro que sentia tentado a "fechar tudo". Hoje geralmente eu só voto pra fechar em coisas que sei (PHP, javascript e por aí vai). Estou evitando me meter em coisas que eu não sei nada

Comment: @mauriciocaserta Boa-vontade não é critério para determinar o placar de uma resposta, o conteúdo dela é que deve ser. Concordo que -9 foi demais, mas daria para entender se ela estivesse com -1.

Comment: Sim, @bigown. Acho que ficaram com dó do rapaz. Então temos um outro problema, e agora, quem poderá nos defender?

Comment: @bigown A outra resposta também não é tão boa assim para ter a pontuação que tem.

Comment: @bfavaretto, vamos ver quantos -1 o cara vai ganhar depois do seu comentário, rsrsrsrsrs

Comment: @bfavaretto Pode ser mesmo.

Comment: Estou me sentido culpado por feito a pergunta. Agora virou essa bola de neve, rsrsrs

Comment: @bigown, estou quase adotando o seguinte critério: Se está rum a resposta, não vou me meter

Comment: @WallaceMaxters seu "maria vai com as outras" :P

Comment: @bfavaretto entendo que boa-vontade não seja critério ou parâmetro de comparação, mas pensando que "daria para entender se ela estivesse com -1", de quem seria esse "-1"? Será que o meu, o seu , e mais 7 pessoas que achassem que apenas -1 estava ótimo, não geraria os 9 votos negativos? Acredito que um comentário para alertar o cara que respondeu, de que "algo errado não está certo" ja era o suficiente, e usando o bom senso, 0 seria o aceitável na minha opinião.

Comment: Não  entendi @bigown. Olha as intimidade!

Comment: @WallaceMaxters "todo mundo" adota o "não vou me meter em resposta ruim". Você só vai fazer o que já é feito.

Comment: @mauriciocaserta Os -9 não são instantâneos; se eu vejo algo errado que já está com vários negativos, eu só coloco mais um se o autor for teimoso, e insistir que o errado está certo, nos comentários.

Comment: @bfavaretto Entendo, usando como exemplo essa mesma resposta, ninguém alertou em NADA nos comentários da reposta do rapaz e taca-lhe "-" !

Comment: @mauriciocaserta houve comentários na resposta sim, mas foram removidos entretanto.

Comment: Agora a resposta com ES6 superou a outra. Talvez a solução para a pergunta seja uma terceira resposta que bote as coisas no lugar e supere as outras em pontuação. Tipo aquelas do Sergio...

Comment: @Sergio, os comentários mostravam a nossa ignorância (a minha pelo menos)

Comment: Ainda não entendi porque tem gente que acha que a resposta "merece mais/menos up/downvotes", como se houvesse uma pontuação ideal que cada resposta merece. Se chegarem 100 pessoas numa resposta, com o mesmo problema, e a resposta resolver para todas elas, o mais adequado é que ela tenha 100 upvotes

Comment: @Math `rebanho` e `manada` precisam de outro alias, `maria-vai-com-as-outras`.

Comment: @Gabe também acho, só não foi o caso do que aconteceu, nem com os negativos, nem com o positivos daquela resposta. A resposta é curiosa, interessante. Naquele caso resolve o problema de zero pessoas.

Comment: Por obséquio, ninguém acha que a pergunta em questão é duplicata de nenhuma das outras mencionadas? Se a resposta for "não", estou me sentindo tentado a ir lá e postar minha própria resposta, aproveitando a "publicidade grátis" mwahaha!

Comment: Boa tarde Sergio e colegas, vou deixar a minha opinião. os votos negativos foram antes da edição, acho que foi justo sim os votos negativos, eu não negativei e nem tinha visto tal resposta, mas provavelmente teria negativado, já que ele não explicava o que o exemplo era sobre ES6, postar um código é legal, mas não postar uma orientação é ruim e ao meu ver a resposta só ficou razoavelmente boa após a edição...

Comment: ...Se nos comentários o AP explicou a resposta (sobre ser ES6) ele fez errado, comentários são descartáveis, ele deveria ter explicado o "minimo" do código, o que ele não fez, não acho que foi um caso de maria vai com as outras. Desculpe mas muitos aqui se esforçam pra fornecer uma resposta de qualidade e que ajude além de quem pergunta, acho que o autor da resposta não entendeu muito bem isto.

Comment: @mgibsonbr dei uma resposta. Mas seria excelente ter uma tua também, ou de outros que queiram ajudar/completar a pergunta e respostas.

Comment: @Sergio Feito! (que foi? eu juro que escrevi a minha depois de ler seu comentário... pode ver o timestamp! rsrs)

Comment: @mgibsonbr ninja :)

Comment: Até achei que o link não apontava pra resposta em questão: já estava +11! +12 agora ^^

Comment: jeje, *ir com o rebanho*, tão antigo quanto o Flautista de Hamelin; por favor, dirigir-se a [philosophy.se].

Comment: não sei como é em Portugal, mas no Brasil há a cultura do linxamento.. rsrs isso se extende para a internet pelos "haters"..  Teem hábito de atirar pedra a esmo..

Comment: Parece que deu resultado @Sergio as vez vale mesmo a pena abrir aqui no meta. :)

Comment: opa. cheguei atrasado, nem deu pra ver os negativos da resposta...

Comment: O cara ganhou +22. Todo mundo ficou solidário com ele. E a resposta que realmente resolveu o problema foi a do @mgibsonbr que nem chega aos pés na pontuação do "amigo injustiçado com -9"

Comment: @WallaceMaxters todos ganharam. A resposta do mgibsonbr vai certamente com o tempo chegar a essa pontuação pela qualidade que tem. Acho que todos aprendemos e a possivel injustiça foi corrigida. Eu vejo todo o processo como positivo e fico contente com o feedback que a comunidade deu.

Comment: @Sergio, dê uma olhada nessa http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/80699/o-que-%c3%a9-o-php-injection-qual-a-diferen%c3%a7a-dele-para-o-sql-injection-e-como-evit/80750#comment164105_80750