# Negativar uma resposta muito ruim e perder pontos

Tags: debate

Eu estava percorrendo o site para resolver uma dúvida sobre regex, encontrei essa pergunta:

[Expressão regular para validar um campo que aceita CPF ou CNPJ](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11045/express%C3%A3o-regular-para-validar-um-campo-que-aceita-cpf-ou-cnpj/13927#13927)

Tem uma resposta que basicamente está fora de contexto, dá pra ver pelo tanto de votos negativos e também em relação à resposta e pergunta.

**Por que eu perco reputação por negativar uma resposta ruim?** Mesmo que seja -1, é estranho, pois não era uma resposta boa, dá a sensação que eu também estou fazendo algo ruim nesse caso.

Comment: É para evitar que alguém saia dando negativos por retalhação e com menos de 125 pontos você não tem esse privilégio

Comment: @rray é que tem casos que é tão óbvio (matematicamente) que a coisa é ruim que não é retaliação, então deveria ser gratuito. Na verdade eu acho que tem várias coisas que precisariam ser revistas e que tornariam o funcionamento do site melhor.

Comment: @bigown no caso de uma resposta como no exemplo que citei na pergunta, eu devo sinalizar como *qualidade muito baixa*  ou apenas negativar?

Comment: http://memegenerator.net/instance2/3394124

Comment: @bigown Me corrija se estiver errado, mas uma resposta dessa os usuários podem remover (se possuir reputação para o mesmo). Então não vejo necessidade de negativar, e sim apenas remover.

Comment: RenanCavalieri e @Bigown eu não vejo o negativo para essa finalidade, e sim para mostrar que algo está errado e/ou não está bom e precise de atenção. Em seu exemplo a resposta já possui -9, creio que -1 não irá fazer diferença, e também acho que por esse motivo já deveria ter sido excluída. Essa é a finalidade de um downvote, para mim, é claro.

Comment: Se alguém der tantos votos negativos que os pontos perdidos sejam uma preocupação, essa pessoa muito provavelmente não agrega muito de positivo para a comunidade. Pessoalmente, negativar uma pergunta já muito negativada e esmaecida me parece ser como chutar cachorro morto. Se for tão ruim assim que realmente mereça infinitos votos negativos seria melhor remover o conteúdo. Do meu ponto de vista, o `-1` exigido é um pequeno preço a se pagar pela responsabilidade de julgamento, evitando que alguns usuários distribuam votos negativos sem pensar.

Comment: @utluiz não digo que esse ponto a menos me incomodou, apenas digo que ele dá a sensação de que estou fazendo algo de errado. Nesse exemplo realmente, talvez eu poderia ter passado a resposta sem negativar, porém é meio que automático votar em respostas que são boas e negativar esse tipo de resposta. Eu poderia comentar que aquela não era sequer uma solução adequada e explicar o porquê, porém isso iria reviver uma discussão de quase 1 ano atrás. Por isso fiz meu segundo posicionamento, **devo sinalizar respostas desse tipo?**

Comment: @RenanCavalieri Como moderador eu não removeria aquela resposta porque não é função da moderação julgar o quesito técnico do quanto aquilo é certo ou errado. No entanto, usuários com certa reputação podem votar pela remoção da pergunta ([ver detalhes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/262149)). Então, minha sugestão seria que você sugerisse aqui no meta a remoção de conteúdo ruim de forma democrática e outros usuários poderiam então votar. Quando tiver mais pontos, você pode fazer isso diretamente na resposta.

Comment: Neste caso acho que o -9 é mesmo bater em cachorro morto como disse o @utluiz. As regras do site não são perfeitas, mas funcionam. Não me parece que eliminar essa retirada de um ponto pudesse melhorar o funcionamento do site.

Comment: @Randrade sim, não fará diferença, mas quando há muitos negativos, não deveria custar nada já que ficou claro que o negativo não foi dado por sacanagem. Mas na verdade, tem soluções melhores para tratar com coisa tão ruim. Tem coisas que precisam ser mudadas.

Comment: E como eu, um pobre e mero mortal com reputação baixa posso ajudar nesse caso? Acredito que é muito incomodo criar uma pergunta no meta só pra remover uma resposta ruim.

Comment: Gamification: Eu penso nisto tudo como um jogo, aonde você tem que gastar alguns pontos que seria equivalente a algo "monetário" em um "jogo normal" pra poder acessar novas áreas ou invocar magias. Pra mim sendo ou não para impedir votos negativos desnecessários, eu acho que o sistema de jogo aonde só ganhamos não é tão divertido assim. Mas... posso estar equivocado :)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento eu invoco a carta "Monstro Negativador" em modo de defesa, e encerro minha jogada. Brincadeira :)

Comment: @RenanCavalieri kkkk, comenta assim nas respostas: *Eu ofereço -1 dos meus pontos como um tributo pra invocar um "downvote" em sua resposta. (Summon!!)* http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_maprj5GOlF1r676j0o1_250.jpg

Comment: Negativar pontos, pra mim, é uma medida extrema, quando autor da pergunta/resposta, não melhora, ou continua postando perguntas/respostas ruins, mesmo após ser avisado.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento sim, como você mesmo disse, é um custo que você tem no julgamento de que algo é bom ou não.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento agora que reparei, eu escrevi errado mesmo kkkkk É negativar uma pergunta/resposta, não sei de onde tirei esse "pontos".

Comment: É tão baratinho o -1 que no fim, não faz diferença, nem pra quem vota nem pra quem recebe o voto. Pela qualidade que se ganha, eu "pago" os meus negativos com prazer. Na verdade eu acho é que o +1 também devia custar, pras pessoas pensarem antes de votar.

Comment: @Bacco realmente, porém confunde quem está iniciando no site, igual eu pensei, "Será que fiz certo? Até perdi ponto".

Comment: @RenanCavalieri acho que eu entendi o ponto de vista, foi uma "cobrança inesperada". Faz sentido.

Answer (score 5):

Antes de julgar o autor da resposta, coloque-se no lugar dele! E gosto de enfatizar isso porque eu já passei por esta experiência, muitos daqui já passaram e muitos ainda haverão de passar. Por isso vou narrar uma historinha:

> João vê uma pergunta interessante. **Acha** que sabe a resposta, ou pelo menos alguma coisa que você acha que vai ajudar o autor da pergunta (Maria) ou outras pessoas que têm algum problema parecido. Então João vai lá e posta uma resposta.
>
> Entretanto, a resposta de João não era boa. Seja porque João não entendeu direito a pergunta, ou talvez a resposta dele tinha alguns problemas ou alguma outra coisa aconteceu.
>
> Maria e um terceiro usuário (Pedro) vão lá e dizem "olha, agradecemos a ajuda, mas não era isso o que devia ser feito". A resposta do João fica lá, talvez com -1 ou -2 votos. Pode até receber um +1 de alguém que simpatize com a tentativa, principalmente se o conteúdo for parcialmente aceitável.
>
> Mas... Por algum motivo, ao invés disso, a resposta do João recebe uma chuva de downvotes. Especialmente se a resposta dele for de fato péssima. Curiosamente, em poucos minutos é possível se buscar no site muitas outras respostas ainda piores que estão com pontuações tais como 0, -1 ou -2, e até algumas com pontuações positivas (sim, já vi muito conteúdo de baixíssima qualidade por aqui, bem pior que essa resposta linkada, com +2 ou +3). Mas por algum motivo, a resposta do João foi a premiada para receber a chuva de downvotes.
>
> E então João perde um monte de reputação no site. Como João ainda é um usuário iniciante com pouca experiência, ele pode achar que não é bem vindo, que não gostam dele, que a comunidade é má, que só aceita quem é da panelinha, etc. Ele pode criar um milhão de teorias da conspiração em sua cabeça. Ou pode ser que não pense nada disso.

Então, eu acho completamente desnecessário punir alguém com chuva de downvotes, a menos que esse alguém esteja realmente agindo de má fé, se comportando de forma ofensiva ou coisa assim, o que não é o caso.

Para piorar, **o usuário não foi chamado para se defender** aqui no tópico. Antes [de mim postar um comentário na resposta dele](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11045/express%C3%A3o-regular-para-validar-um-campo-que-aceita-cpf-ou-cnpj/13927#comment215054_13927), **NINGUÉM** se deu ao trabalho de chamá-lo para o debate no meta acerca de sua resposta. A maioria dos usuários deste site, em especial os iniciantes, não são pessoas que ficam avidamente procurando tópicos no meta, e acabam ficando sem entender o que está acontecendo. E mesmo se assim fossem, ser surpreendindo com um monte de gente esculhambando você em público sem que você sequer tenha sido avisado disso é algo extremamente desagradável. E desculpe a sinceridade, mas a este tipo de atitude é algo a que eu dou o nome de **covardia**.

[Aonde eu já recebi chuva de downvotes acompanhado com seção de esculhambação e escrachamento em público no meta e sem ser chamado para me defender (ou ser chamado apenas tardiamente)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/), em especial quando isso acontece mais de uma vez, a minha decisão é simples: Deixar de contribuir e não voltar mais, ou então só voltar depois de alguns meses ou anos. Esse tipo de atitude é uma coisa totalmente desnecessária e que destroi completamente a motivação de se participar em uma comunidade, pois me recuso a participar de comunidades que têm este tipo de postura com os seus usuários.

Sério, a resposta que o usuário deu é péssima de fato, mas esse nível de esculhambação pública ao qual a comunidade acaba sujeitando-o, que é evidenciado pelo +0/-9 na resposta dele e um tópico no meta com o propósito de atacá-lo sem que ele tenha sido chamado para se defender é uma coisa desnecessária, irracional e covarde. Alguns comentários explicando o porquê da resposta estar errada e uma pontuação não inferior a -3 já seria mais que suficiente.

Para piorar, ainda se pede que a reputação não seja subtraída de quem deu o downvote. Para que? Para aumentar ainda mais o circo que está sendo promovido com o objetivo de esculhambar e prejudicar ainda mais o desafortunado autor da resposta?

Comment: Eu acredito que nesse caso você também deveria se colocar no meu lugar, também sou iniciante, concordo com você em algumas coisas, mas achei sua resposta um tanto quanto agressiva pelo simples fato de que eu estava perguntando a respeito do comportamento, perder -1 mostra que é algo ruim que o usuário está fazendo, então questionei para confirmar a hipótese e não para denegrir o autor da resposta. Vendo as respostas, mudei meu posicionamento a respeito da sinalização, se ela deveria ser empregada.

Comment: Fiz uma justificativa de não ter comentado na resposta em um dos meus comentários, além de que a comunidade fez comentários na resposta do usuário, porém o mesmo quis manter  como estava. Apenas ressalto que você está equivocado em afirmar que eu fiquei incomodado pelo -1, assim como afirmar que minha intenção foi de denegrir o autor,  restante já está esclarecido em comentários na minha própria pergunta.

Comment: Sua dúvida é perfeitamente válida, @RenanCavalieri, mas o link para a resposta foi desnecessário. O sistema é o mesmo para todas as respostas. Sua pergunta não é exclusiva desse caso, então pra quê? Claro que todo mundo tem seus motivos quando faz algo, e gosto de acreditar que aqui no SOPt a intenção é quase sempre boa. Mas mesmo ações bem intencionadas podem ser mal-vistas. A sua foi e a do Victor também, mas é visível que ele claramente tem mais do que esse caso pra levar em consideração. Todos devemos exercitar a paciência aqui hoje.

Comment: @RenanCavalieri A ideia é que se você está disposto a punir ou atacar algum outro usuário, mesmo que isso possa ser legítimo, então que esta ação não seja algo a ser feito de graça. O downvote é uma coisa poderosa, porém é também perigosa, e por isso só deve ser utilizada se você tiver certeza que terá algum benefício, e por este motivo ele tem um preço (que inclusive acho ser barato demais).

Comment: @Pablo, compreendo, realmente não havia motivos para postar o link da resposta, achei que não teria problemas e queria apenas demonstrar o caso.

Comment: @VictorStafusa eu realmente postei porque queria saber a opinião do pessoal a respeito do que deveria ser feito, justamente porque eu também sou novo, sua resposta soou um pouco agressiva como se tivesse tomado por base experiências que você teve, como citou, porém acredite, não é o caso, eu não tive e nem estou disposto a atacar ninguém, concordo com várias coisas a respeito mas apenas sugeria que pegasse mais leve nesse caso. A respeito de não chamar o usuário ao debate, foi justamente porque eu pensei que isso sim iria ser motivo de esculachar ele, além de que a resposta dele já tem um ano.

Comment: O Sirius nunca quis muita conversa... Mas... onde é que tem `um tópico no meta com o propósito de atacá-lo`? Este aqui não é....

Answer (score -1):

Pelo que entendo, o motivo principal é prover um balanço nas distribuições de votos. O decremento acontece também para evitar abusos. Apesar de ser ineficaz no sentido de inibir votos de má fé ou descuido.

Para inibir abusos o decremento deveria ser maior. Por exemplo, -50.
Muitos que votam negativo, sem pensar direito em suas ações, passariam a pensar melhor. Ou não..

Há muitos votos negativos que ajudam, e são válidos. Mas há também muitos votos por retaliação ou meramente por má interpretação de texto.
Também há aqueles que vão na onda dos outros ([o rebanho](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4407/%C3%89-preciso-ter-calma-refletir-em-caso-de-d%C3%BAvida-e-se-n%C3%A3o-souber-n%C3%A3o-ir-com-o-reb)).

Todavia, é muito complexo determinar o que é um voto correto ou não. Como exemplo,  um voto negativo legítimo e correto receber um decremento de -50, não seria justo para quem votou.

Precisaríamos de um exército de "juízes" **altamente qualificados** e **imparciais** para acompanhar todas as postagens. Isso é inviável.

Por isso, acredito que mantiveram a regra com apenas 1 decremento para votos negativos. Pois parece ser algo "menos nocivo" para ambos os lados e descomplica o assunto.